# Mobile rendering issues with right side of nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two issues that I'm trying to solve with the right side of my nav bar.

1) I'd like to have the nav look like this "Login | Contact"
- Currently there's no divider in between, but when I add the divider line, it doesn't line up after the Login text.

2) When viewing the nav on mobile. The Login link stays in the correct place, but the "Contact" link falls down below the logo. How do I get it to lineup along side of the logo>

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/waaBbWFaI1

Here's my HTML:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container topnav">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://red.org/wp-content/plugins/a8c-stripe/img/red_logo.png" alt="Red Exchange">
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a>|</li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you looked into flexbox? This will solve issue #2. See the already posted answer for a better way of adding the separator.

Comment: No I haven't looked into flexbox. Can you show me on bootply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all I think adding the Divider like this

```
<li><a href="#">Login</a>|</li>
```

Seems to be a bad idea..Imagine You need the space that you are using for the list element for the label and it doesnt have any space left..So what it does is basically that it, puts it into the next line..
I would suggest you to do something like .. giving your anchor tag element(better if it would be wrapped around a div) a border to right

Another solution would be:

```
  <li><a class="login" href="#">Login</a></li>
  <li>|</li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

This would put the divider between those elements but not at the right place just check it. To put it into the right place you will have to give each list element following css.

```
ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% // only if its already around a header
  li {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 15%; // each element gets 15% of the parents width
     height: 100;

  }
}
```

2. Learn CSS, the problem is that without knowing any css you will not be able to have your website, as you wish.
   Issue is, that both are block elements login and contact and if you wrap it and there is no place because the font-size is too big and the elements take the whole space, they will automatically wrap..to the next line.

Sorry, i hope you understood my english.